# TinyMCE looping through all editors, get a property and its related editor value

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have the following HTML:

```
<div data-edit="myeditor1">
    Test 1234
</div>
<div>
    NotEditable
</div>
<div data-edit="myeditor2">
    Test 1234
</div>
```

And I instanciate TinyMCE with the following JS:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'*[data-edit]',
    inline: true
});
```

The editors display nicely,

How can I get each editor's value and "data-edit" atribute value?

I tried looping through editors with:

```
for (inst in tinyMCE.editors) {
    var c = tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent;
    console.log(c);
}
```

But that didn't do it,

Tried also:

```
$("*[data-edit]").each(function() {
    var this_att = $(this).data("edit");
    var thishtml = tinymce.get(this_att).getContent();
});
```

That didn't work,

How can I loop through all editors, get the "data-edit" property and its related editor value?

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: What version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: 5.0.4 (2019-04-23)

Comment: I'm not proud of my bad coding skills, but I think this will at least get the data-edit value:

    $(tinyMCE.editors[inst].targetElm).data('edit')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't manage to make code-indent in comment so I'll make an whole answer, it's not pretty but at last it gets your `data-edit` attribute.

```
for (inst in tinyMCE.editors) {
  let c = tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent();
  let edit = $(tinyMCE.editors[inst].targetElm).data('edit')
  console.log(edit + '=' + c);
}
```

Comment: This line doesn`t return the editable html: tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent

Comment: ahh it just needed .getContent();

Comment: Haha, I just copied the the code from the question, I didn't check the lines I didn't write myself ;)

Comment: A small note, tried to run the code and got duplicates, so I would go with:
    for (let inst = 0; inst < tinyMCE.editors.length; inst++) {
        let c = tinyMCE.editors[inst].getContent();